# Optimize recovery after memory pressure

Tags: linux, performance, swap

I have a machine that compiles large codebases, with 32 threads and 16 GiB RAM.

The RAM is on the small side, but usually sufficient. When it isn't, however, the machine swaps out a few GiB of memory, and several of the compiler processes slow down significantly.

These remain slow even after memory pressure returns to normal, because the processes have a somewhat random access pattern to the pages that have been swapped out, so data is swapped back in one page at a time.

Is there a way to optimize this, e.g. by having the kernel proactively read back pages from disk if there is enough free memory available?

Comment: I would simply disable swapping altogether and let overcommiting processes die. From what I can see swapping creates more problems for you, than solves anything.